# Should I use webservice?

Tags: web-services

There are 3 different applications that has data which is not properly formatted. I am planning to write an application to properly format this data before entering into the DB. which is the best approach to make all the applications to call this formatting application? Should the formatting application be a web service called by all other application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they're indeed different applications (and not, say, three controllers and/or actions of a single webapp), yes, webservice would fit quite nice, I suppose.

Still there's the other way around: you can set up a simple application which will be called in the shell context. Or, if all these apps use the same platform, just create a 'library utility class' which will be called by this very platform.